# Find the general solution of second linear differential equation, given that one solution is polynomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is $(x-1)y''-(x+1)y'+2y=0$, and it is given a solution type, which is polynomial.
The question is to find the general solution.
I looked up the general solution and it is $y=C_1(x^2+1)+C_2e^x$, but i don't know how to solve the question with the given data.

Comment: I do not understand. You have found the general solution. Could you explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Considering a polynomial solution such as $y_1 = a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2$ after substitution into the DE we obtain

$$
2a_0-a_1-2a_2+a_1 x \equiv 0
$$

so following with $a_1 = 0, 2a_0-2a_2 = 0$ we arrive at

$$
y_1 = a_2(x^2+1)
$$

Assuming now that the other independent solution has the structure $y_2 = a_2(x)(x^2+1)$ after substitution we arrive at

$$
a''_2(x) = \left(1+\frac{2}{x-1}-\frac{4x}{x^2+1}\right)a'_2(x)
$$

so now we can solve for $a_2(x)$ and then obtain $y_2$

Comment: I was wondering if the polynomial solution could be of higher order? Can't it contain x^3?